# sum of the values of the input array in reverse

Tags: php

You can calculate the sum of the values of the input array in reverse order using a loop:

```
$input = (6,60,38,44,44,38,60,6);
```

Here is output

This will give you the expected output: Array ( [0] => 296 [1] => 290 [2] => 230 [3] => 192 [4] => 148 [5] => 104 [6] => 66 [7] => 6 )

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is not a "code writing" service, it's a place where we help you to solve your problems. The first step is usually to show us what you've tried, and describe how it's failing compared to what you want and expect.

Comment: Hello greg sir i new sir this is not a code writing service but am trying hard i dont iunderstand how to start it my whole web is ready but this function i totaly dont understand how to start blank please give me help @Greg Schmidt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You obviously need to walk through the input array and add each new output element as the sum of the current input value and the last sum you computed:

```
<?php
$input = array_reverse()[6,60,38,44,44,38,60,6]);
$output = [];
array_walk($input, function($i) use (&$output) {
    array_unshift($output, $output[0] + $i);
});
print_r($output);
```

To suppress a warning about a non exiting array element you could use the ternary operator:

```
array_unshift($output, array_key_exists(0, $output) ? $output[0] + $i : $i);
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 296
    [1] => 290
    [2] => 230
    [3] => 192
    [4] => 148
    [5] => 104
    [6] => 66
    [7] => 6
)
```

Comment: That adds left to right instead of right to left. Maybe reverse the array first? But same output since the input was symmetrical. Also will get an error or warning depending on php version and settings "Undefined array key 0".   Can probably do `@$output[0]` instead.

Comment: @KevinY Yes, correct, I originally accepted that warning, since it is irrelevant for the task itself. I made an update pointing out that detail, also reversed the array.